# Perp notation question

Tags: notation

What does the symbol $\perp$ mean? I saw this on a paper where some entity outputs $\perp$.

Comment: Halt, stop there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen it used to denote 'nil', e.g. as a return value by some entity to indicate that it has nothing to return, or as a placeholder for a value which will be instantiated at a later time.

One example to see it used this way would be the [Introduction to Reliable and Secure Distributed Programming](https://www.distributedprogramming.net/) textbook, where the authors use it to indicate uninitialized values and error conditions, as mentioned in the comments.

But it's speculation unless you can provide some context.

Comment: My speculation is it denotes that an entity just outputs "garbage" but I am not sure. Returning nothing makes sense too but are there any other situation that $\perp$ is used to mean something else?

Comment: It's also often used to indicate an error.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that $\perp$ is often a *distinguished* error symbol. So the algorithm is not only turning in an answer that is incorrect, but one that it *knows* it is incorrect.

Comment: It is also sometimes used to represent than an algorithm did not terminate - for example, in [haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom). I have also seen it be used to represent "False", and Top (⊤) to represent "True" (this is their meaning in [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)). Context is everything.

Comment: I just saw in Goldreich's Foundations of Cryptography book Volume 2, page 616 that $\perp$ denotes a special error symbol and in addition, $\lambda$ denotes the empty string.